# filename in GET variable breaks PHP session

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a MVC-framework. Every request should be processed by the index.php file. It's working fine, except for request which ended with a common extension such as jpg,gif,png. My PHP session is gone in such cases

My htaccess-file is the following:

```
php_flag display_errors on

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /projecten/xxxxxxxx/index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]

ErrorDocument 403 /errors/403.html
ErrorDocument 404 /errors/404.html
```

Anyone who has a solution for me?

**EDIT:** My problem is on the server, on my local machine everything is OK, but on the online server the problem occurs.

Comment: Can you show an example of such a request and explain in more detail what happens? What URL are you being redirected to exactly?

Comment: For example this URL: http://www.domain.com/file.jpg. According to the htaccess the url should be http://www.domain.com/index.php?route=file.jpg. That works, but my session is gone. If i use http://www.domain.com/file.jp (other unknown extension) everything is fine.

Comment: Does `domain.com/file.jpg` physically exist on your server? Because you're blocking the rewrite for files that exist (`!-f`)

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mention, but that file don't exist, so i can read my GET-variable 'route', value of that is 'file.jpg'

Comment: Hmm, that seems really weird. What is your session ID in those cases? Does the request's domain change? (www.domain.com vs. domain.com)

Comment: My session ID changes each time i reload the URL (http://www.domain.com/file.jpg). The domain is not changing..

Comment: But you are getting the expected result? (A JPG file or whatever) in that case, you should probably show some code - how are you initiating the session and how are you dealing with the GET variable

Comment: I'm not getting the expecting result. The JPG-file don't exist at that location. But i need the filename to use it in my code. I can read the 'route' GET-variable, but my session changes each time, that's not what i want. My index.php is nothing special, it reads the 'route' variable and read the segments and starts the right controllers.